# Attempting to group x and y coordinates into ranges and calculate the volume in each range

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

First off, here is my data:

[image: data]

My goal is to essentially create a grid that'll group the volume of data within each section. At the end of the day, I'd want to know how many data points are within, lets say, X (-73.8, -73.9) and Y (40.5, 40,6). I've seen the pandas [cut function.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) But that only seems to work in one dimension.

How would I go about doing this for two dimensions? If further explanation is necessary, feel free to ask.

My initial attempt:

```
df.groupby(pd.cut(df.dropoff_latitude, np.arange(40.60, 41.0, 0.05))).count()
```

[image]

This is pretty much what i'm looking for except I would want the latitude coordinates grouped similarly.

I believe I figured it out:

```
df.groupby([pd.cut(df.dropoff_latitude, np.arange(40.60, 41.0, 0.05)),pd.cut(df.dropoff_longitude, np.arange(xlim[0], xlim[1], 0.05))]).count()
```

[image]

If there are cleaner solutions, please let me know.

Comment: Hey, can you provide a MWE of what you have so far? Have you tried something straightforward like filtering out your points with a series of "IFs"? (for each point, if -73.8 < point.x < -73.9 and 40.5 > point.y >40.6 then total+=1 sort of thing)

Comment: To clarify that last: I'm saying that to bin points within a bounding area you're really just asking if the coordinate lies between an upper and lower bound. It seems straightforward to write a function to do this, so I'm asking if you have tried this (and what the problem is) or if you haven't, what's stopping you.

Comment: That was my initial thought and I should have mentioned that. I guess I'm looking for a more efficient way of doing so. I used the cut function but I haven't been able to apply it to both dimensions simultaneously.